# when we trigger lambda function from s3. how to get the logs that lambda is triggred or not. i want to do this with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Need to get output when trigger lambda function from s3. need to know whether lambda function is triggered or not. I can check in the console but need to be done with the terraform

I tried with resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" but no I don't know weather lambda triggered or not

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get an alarm notification then this means that your Lambda executed without any issues. That's the whole point of alarms: To be notified when things go wrong.
So you should test your lambda and see if the errors are reported in "Monitoring", check if the alarm is triggered and the notifications sent. In addition you can trigger notifications when your alarm goes from alarm to normal

You could send an SNS notification at the end of your Lambda code, but this approach would be cumbersome, as you would have to figure what' missing.

Setting up your Lambda and the alarms with Terraform is another task You should come up with specific questions about this. What you've tried and what does not work.

Comment: thanks for reply spiff, do you have an idea how do I need to call thought aws SDK with go in terratest, to get cloud watch events like log group name and log stream name